# Drupal and jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6

I have turned on jquery-update module for drupal 6, but jQuery was not not loaded, I have checked page source, no jQuery here.

Are there any steps I need to do to load jQuery?

I have copy all jQuery files to the `misc` folder.

It just is not loaded by front page

Answer (score 3):

Drupal does not load jQuery unless you add a specific script on a given page using drupal_add_js in a module or your theme. The jQuery files themselves are library files you build upon, and without calling drupal_add_js, do not actually do anything on their own.

[Using drupal_add_js](http://drupal.org/node/304255)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the .js file in your .info file just make sure to clear cache after you have added the line of code to include the jquery library.  i think it is scripts[ ]= file directory/name...like js/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `JS` and `CSS` files in your `.info` file or under `.module` file inside the `hook_init()`. Do not include outside the function it will break the drupal working.